# How to change the targetContentOffset of a UICollectionView in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, uiscrollview, uicollectionview

In my `UIViewController` I have a `UICollectionView`. The delegate is set properly. It just works fine. `isPagingEnabled` is set to `true`. But now I want to change the paging-positions I tried it within `scrollViewWillEndDragging`, because in the documentation it says:

> Your application can change the value of the targetContentOffset parameter to adjust where the scrollview finishes its scrolling animation.

This functions is called properly but the only thing happens when I want to set a new Endpoint, the `UICollectionView` scrolls to 0.

This is my code:

```
func scrollViewWillEndDragging(_ scrollView: UIScrollView, withVelocity velocity: CGPoint, targetContentOffset: UnsafeMutablePointer<CGPoint>) {
       print(scrollView.contentOffset, "actual Offset")
       print(targetContentOffset.pointee, "future offset")


       targetContentOffset.pointee = CGPoint(x: 100, y: 0)
       print(targetContentOffset.pointee, "new future offset")
}
```

At the print("new future offset"), it prints the right value. So it seems the value is mutated after this function.

Comment: Does your collection views' scroll direction set to horizontal?

Comment: Yes. Its the normal UICollectionViewFlowLayout with .horizontal

Comment: I can't what is `targetContentOffset.pointee`. Is it variable?

Comment: Sorry my English is not very good. What exactly do you mean?

Comment: Share declaration code of `targetContentOffset`

Comment: scrollViewWillEndDragging has the parameter targetContentOffset. This is a  UnsafeMutablePointer<CGPoint>. With targetContentOffset.pointee you can access the ContentOffset where it will snap in.

Apple says:

Comment: Accessing the instance referenced by this pointer.

Answer (score 2):

```
func targetContentOffset(forProposedContentOffset proposedContentOffset: CGPoint, 
   withScrollingVelocity velocity: CGPoint) -> CGPoint
```

**Description:**

> If you want the scrolling behavior to snap to specific boundaries, you
>   can override this method and use it to change the point at which to
>   stop. For example, you might use this method to always stop scrolling
>   on a boundary between items, as opposed to stopping in the middle of
>   an item.

Override this layout method instead of directly changing value of targetContentOffset.

If you want the scrolling behavior to snap to specific boundaries, you can override this method and use it to change the point at which to stop. For example, you might use this method to always stop scrolling on a boundary between items, as opposed to stopping in the middle of an item.

**Docs:**
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uicollectionviewlayout/1617729-targetcontentoffset

Comment: @Quintus_2 So I think that you do something outside of this logic. Please share more details.

Comment: I thing I do nothing special. Do you think the sizeForItemAt from UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout could cause this problem?

Comment: After some testing I would say that targetContentOffset in my code has the behavior as it would change the point where the "drag" stops...